# Getting connected System in a LAN network-Java

Tags: java, client, server, lan

I have a `Server-Client` program in `Java` where I need to find the `IP's` of the client system and assign it to a `JLabel` . I have a code for finiding out the `IP's` but it takes much time to find all. Can anyone give me alternative for this code and assigning IP to JLabel so that when I click the JLabel i can communicate with that particular client.

```
 void get_list() throws IOException
    {
        try {
            InetAddress localhost = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            // this code assumes IPv4 is used
            byte[] ip = localhost.getAddress();

            for (int i = 1; i <= 254; i++)
            {
                ip[3] = (byte)i;
                InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByAddress(ip);
                if (address.isReachable(1000))
                {
                    System.out.println(address + " machine is turned on and can be pinged");

                    //***********here how do i assign all the valid connected ip to diffrent jlabel's and i need a alternative for this code
                }
                else if (!address.getHostAddress().equals(address.getHostName()))
                {
                    System.out.println(address + " machine is known in a DNS lookup");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println(address + " the host address and host name are equal, meaning the host name could not be resolved");
                }
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test_Frame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong. Better way is when client connect to server, attach the ip in some holder, and then broadcast it. You do not need to search network for clients, clients must search for your server(by ip and port).

Comment: How can I know when a client connects to my server? Is there any way to know this? When my client connects to the server i should get notified.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question, all the client are connected to the server I'm searching for clients just to communicate with them using JButton/JLabel.

Comment: What server do you use? Or where do you have ServerSocket object witch wait and accept the connection? What is the implementation of server-client connection?

Comment: Ya i have a Serversocket objects which waits for the connection.

Comment: I need to send details for the client system to server system through the button click.

Comment: You can get all information you need from <code>
List<Client> clients = new ArrayList<>();
Socket connection = serverSocket.accept();
Client client = new Client(connection);
clients.add(client);
</code>
And you can make a observer pattern to broadcast message with all IP addresses to client. Then client app check the new IP i send a message to user.

Comment: Will this arraylist give me all clients connected to my serversystem?

Comment: Yes, list will persist connections in RAM and you can get all of them by looping it.

Comment: what i `List<Client> clients = new ArrayList<>();` here? It gives me a error.

Comment: Yes, you need to create Client class. Where you can wrap content from Socket.